# Re-entry to EU with Spain Schengen visa

Tags: schengen, international-travel, schengen-visas, multiple-entry

I'm a UK resident with non-UK passport and Spanish Schengen visa, Type C, valid for Schengen states (written as estados Schengen), Multi-entry, valid for 6 months with duration of 90 days. I entered Spain a month ago for my first entry for 4 days and then stayed in Germany after for 3 days and went back home.

Next week I'm planning to go to France and Germany for total of ~10 days. Will I get in trouble since my itinerary this time does not include travels to Spain?

Thank you!

Comment: No. Your given itinerary was only for the first visit.